# How to install .apk file to emulator?

Tags: android, installation

How to install the application in `*.apk` file into the Android emulator?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167636/how-to-install-an-apk-on-the-emulator-in-android-studio

Answer (score 19):

launch the emulator

install with :

```
$> adb install fileexplorer.apk
```

then click on the icon on the emulator

Answer (score 8):

> adb devices
>   --> It will give list of devices running by your SDK
>   --> If there is only one device...use this command
>
> adb install ".apk"

--> If there are multiple devices running then you need to select the emulator

> adb -s emulator-5556 install ".apk"

Answer (score 2):

Windows:

1. Execute the emulator.
2. Start the console (Windows XP), Run -> type cmd, and move to the platform-tools     folder of SDK directory.
3. Paste the APK file in the 'platform-tools' folder.
4. Then type the following command.

   ```
     adb install [apk file name]
   ```

   Example:

   ```
     adb install gaurav.apk
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Go to ADT Bundle->SDK -> Platform Tools -> paste the .apk file.

**Command Prompt:**

adb install filename.apk

**Eg:**

[image: eg]

Answer (score 1):

Well you can have a look at these tutorials if you are not able to do it the way Stephane said it.
[Install](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-install-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator) Tutorial
[Uninstall](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-uninstall-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator) Tutorial
Hope it will help you as a beginner..tc

Answer (score 1):

Run emulator -> drag and drop yourApp.apk into emulator screen. Works in android studio.Credit goes to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36778246/3926727).