# How do I Install .apk files in the android emulator?

Tags: android

I want to install my .apk file in android emulator.But I have multiple emulators opened(5554,5556) and i don't want to close any one of the emulator how to install a .apk file in an emulator when there is multiple emulators are opened?

Comment: It's very easy if you are using eclipse for development. Just select the emulator that you want to deploy to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can tell `adb` which device you want to connect to.

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install something.apk
```

(from the host). I am not sure the numbers you gave are the "serial numbers", so check with

```
adb devices
```

Comment: You can also use -e if there's only one running emulator. Run `adb` at the command line to see this switch described.

Comment: i am using xamarin for build android app, this command is not working for me, can you tell me how can i install the something.apk into that xamarin emulator ?

Comment: Did you try with the `-e` (`adb -e install something.apk`)? Did you use the correct device ID? Is the emulator _running_? (Otherwise I don't know; I didn't use Xamarin).

Comment: Using Visual Studio you can run adb from Tools>Android>Android Adb Command Prompt

Answer (score 2):

Use -s command line option with the name of emulator device, e.g.

```
#adb -s emulator-5554 install ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check with this URLs

[How to Install APK Files on Android Device Emulator](http://blog.freewarelovers.com/2010/08/how-to-install-apk-files-on-android.html)

[Tips: How to install apk files on Android Emulator](http://openhandsetmagazine.com/2008/01/tips-how-to-install-apk-files-on-android-emulator/)

[How to install .apk file to emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919149/how-to-install-apk-file-to-emulator)

Comment: adb -s emulator-5556 install helloWorld.apk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install an external apk in your emulator, you need to use adb line code

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple app to open the apk file on your emulator. Here is the code https://stackoverflow.com/a/35339372/4924755