# How to install apk files on my android emulator with Eclipse?

Tags: android

I have eclipse and ADT and android SDK installed and I want to test apk files on my emulator.

I followed guides from stackoverflow, like this: [How do I Install .apk files in the android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815054/how-do-i-install-apk-files-in-the-android-emulator)

but these guides doesnt works a this point: I dont know where i have to put the APK file. For example, this command:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install something.apk
```

It fails because can't find my apk file. Where i have to put it?

Comment: Are you trying to test your own applications on the emulator or some downloaded application-apk files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can put it anywhere on your system, just specify the path as part of your command line:

```
C:\android-sdk\platform-tools> adb -s emulator-5554 install C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myapp.apk
```

Or, change into the directory your APK is in first, then run your command:

```
C:\> cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
C:\Users\Me\Desktop> adb -s emulator-5554 install myapp.apk
```

*Note: The above assumes you're on Windows, substitute UNIX-style paths if you're on Linux or Mac OSX.*

Comment: Hello @justin, my command prompt said that adb is not recognized as internal or external program.

Comment: @Pritom, You need to make sure that `adb` is in your `PATH`, or that your working directory is the `\tools` directory in your Android SDK folder.

Answer (score 7):

Add these lines to your path variable

```
C:\............\Android\android-sdk
C:\............\Android\android-sdk\tools
C:\............\Android\android-sdk\plateform-tools
```

1. Run your emulator by typing the following command on command prompt

   emulator -avd
2. Run the another command prompt window and type the following command

   adb -install ......path of apk file......./Appname.apk

Answer (score 2):

You can start the command console and type

If the emulator is already running.

```
adb install <filepath/filename.apk>
```

if the file is in same directory, else specify the path of the filename.