# How to install app from Android Studio on emulator (maybe using Gradle)?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator, android-studio

I'm normally testing my android app on a physical device, but today I want to do some testing using an emulator. So I created one and it's running fine. I now want to install my app on my emulator. I normally install the app on my device using the Gradle task "installDebug". In the list of Gradle tasks I can't find anything which refers to the emulator though. Although this should be an easy thing to do, I can't find any place in Android Studio to do this.

So I found [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167636/how-to-install-a-apk-on-emulator-in-android-studio) which explains a way to do it from the command line. Although I'm not afraid of the terminal it would be great if I can just do it from within Android studio/IntelliJ so it goes quick and easy.

Any tips on how to install my app on the emulator from within Android Studio (either using a Gradle task or not) would be great!

Comment: You can just "Run >" the app. It will be (re-)installed automatically and stopped if an old version is running.

Answer (score 3):

Emulator instances act just like physical devices for the purposes of the `installDebug` task in Gradle, in ADB, and the **Android Debug Monitor**. If you only have an emulator running and no physical device connected, most things will simply use the emulator by default without needing to ask you; if you have an emulator as well as devices, then you may need to choose which one to use in the same way you would if you had multiple physical devices.