# How to install facebook apk file in ANDROID STUDIO emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, facebook-android-sdk, android-install-apk

I am trying to install facebook apk file in android studio emulator but failed all time. I will be thankful if someone provide me step by step works to install apk in **ANDROID STUDIO** emulator in details.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy the Apk file into the platform-tools of your SDK folder then open command prompt go to the directory of your SDK and enter "adb install filename.apk"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167636/how-to-install-a-apk-on-emulator-in-android-studio 
above link has step by step instrucions 
Thank you