# Open file APK after download

Tags: java, android, android-studio

http://pastebin.com/aKUyw6nX

I searched the internet but I have solved my problem or the code given was not compatible

My question is, how do i open apk file after download?

Comment: Are you trying to run the apk in an emulator within AndroidStudio? If so, the following may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167636/how-to-install-a-apk-on-emulator-in-android-studio

Comment: See this question about installing an APK file using Android intents: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Answer (score 0):

### Install from PC:

1. Download the Andorid SDK
2. Connect your phone to the PC via USB, make sure the USB Debugging option is ON under Developer Option in your phone settings.
3. Once you are done try to use these commands. `adb devices` to check the connection to your device and then if everything is OK try `adb install <filename>.apk` Make sure you input the correct path to the file or simply copy the apk into adb directory.

*adb* usually resides into *adt-bundle-$version/sdk/platform-tool*

### Install from device:

1. Go to the *settings*
2. Enable *Unknown sources* in the *security* section
3. Click on the apk file

Comment: No, what makes the application is a download apk file, I wish after downloading the open

Comment: Sorry can you detail..I don't get what you say