# how to install apps in android emulator permanently?

Tags: android, android-emulator

i would like to install some android apps in emulator like google maps and other.My problem is i want the installation is permanent.I follow the link for [installing apk file in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919149/how-to-install-apk-file-to-emulator). With out permanent installation it is very hard for testing a application so can any one tell me solution or any other alternate solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by **permanent installation**?

Comment: Looks like you are wiping data on every run

Comment: Also, please explain why, without "permanent installation", you think that "it is very hard for testing a application". What specific problems are you encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean exactly by "permanent". An application installed with "adb install " will persist in the AVD you have created, unless you use "wipe data" on every run, which is really not recommended.

Only applications that are pre-installed on the system image cannot be removed (but they still can be disabled in later Android versions, which does the same except the files are not removed, and you can later re-enable it).

Comment: Thank for giving answer.By using your answer i solved my problem.And sorry for little ambiguity in my question i.e  "permanent".once again Thanks.

Comment: Note that a "Cold Boot" of the emulator also removes all installed apps.

Comment: i'm having the same issue even tho im not using any "wipe data" or resetting , my command to start the emulator is very simple : emulator.exe -avd <avdnamehere>, that is no extra lines and yet each start i find the previous apps get wiped !!!!